# Classes(Odometer)- Error Message

Tags: c++, debugging, class

I was wondering if anyone could give me a clue as to what these error messages mean when I try to compile my code.

Here is the error I get:
in function 'int main()':
not  match for 'operator<<'in 'std::operator<<[with_Traits = std::char_traits(((std::basic_ostr...

and it repeats for a while.

I want to post my full code just so you have a idea of what my assignment is, it not that long! =)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Odometer

{
public:

Odometer();

void reset();
void totalfuel();

void input_miles(int getmiles);
void Odometer::set_fuel_efficiency(double fuel_efficiency);

int gallonsUsed;

private:
int milesDriven;
double fuel_efficiency;
int getmiles;   
};

Odometer::Odometer()
{   
milesDriven = 0;
fuel_efficiency = 0;    
}

void Odometer::reset()
{
milesDriven = 0;
}

void Odometer::totalfuel()
{
fuel_efficiency = (milesDriven/gallonsUsed);
}

void Odometer::input_miles(int miles_driven)
{
milesDriven = milesDriven + miles_driven;

}

void Odometer::set_fuel_efficiency(double Fuel_efficiency)
{
fuel_efficiency = Fuel_efficiency;
}

double Odometer::getgallons()
{
return milesDriven/fuel_efficiency;
} 

// ======================
// main function
// ======================
int main()
{
// Two test trips
Odometer trip1, trip2;

trip1.reset();
trip1.set_fuel_efficiency(45);
trip1.input_miles(100);
cout << "For your fuel-efficient small car:" << endl;
cout << "After 100 miles, " << trip1.totalfuel() << " gallons used." << endl;
trip1.input_miles(50);
cout << "After another 50 miles, " << trip1.totalfuel() << " gallons used." << endl;

trip2.reset();
trip2.set_fuel_efficiency(13);
trip2.input_miles(100);
cout << "For your gas guzzler:" << endl;
cout << "After 100 miles, " << trip2.totalfuel() << " gallons used." << endl;
trip2.input_miles(50);
cout << "After another 50 miles, " << trip2.totalfuel() << " gallons used." << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What would you expect `cout << void` to print?

`totalfuel()` returns `void`, and you're passing it as a parameter to `cout::operator <<`. Did you mean to return something from the method?

Perhaps:

```
double Odometer::totalfuel()
{
    fuel_efficiency = (milesDriven/gallonsUsed);
    return fuel_efficiency;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`totalFuel()` returns void. I think you meant to invoke the `getgallons()` method instead.